# Angular2 webpack and css loader

Tags: angular, webpack, css-loader

I have a problem with angular 2 and webpack.
The problem is that if I use relative paths in my css file like 
"background: url("./../images/squares.gif") center left no-repeat;"
I get errors when I build the app:

**"15% 19/206 build modulesModuleBuildError: Module build failed: SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL"**

my webpack config is:

```
loaders: [
...
            {
                test: /\.css$/,
                exclude: helpers.root('src', 'app'),
                loaders:[ExtractTextPlugin.extract('style', 'css-loader'), 'to-string', 'css']
            },
            {
                test: /\.css$/,
                include: helpers.root('src', 'app'),
                loader: ['raw']
            }
...
]
```

Can anybody help me?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have a look at this thread: 
https://github.com/AngularClass/angular2-webpack-starter/issues/759
This would help you.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to it by changing:

**this**

```
{
   test: /\.css$/,
   exclude: helpers.root('src', 'app'),
   loaders:[ExtractTextPlugin.extract('style', 'css-loader'), 'to-string', 'css']
}
```

**to**

```
{
  test: /\.css$/,
  exclude: helpers.root('src', 'app'),
  loader: 'style-loader!css-loader'
}
```